# wanna know how to get odd number from using list

Tags: python

I want to know how I can get the number of odd numbers in the list that i input.

For example if the input[1, 3, 31, 42, 52] the program will print out 'there are 3 odd number'

```py
number = list(input('list: ')) 
total = 0 

for a in number : 
    a = int(a) 
    if a % 2 == 1 : 
        total = total + 1 
print("odd number : %d 개" % total)
```

In the code snippet you can see the attempt that I have made, however I do not know how to apply a 'list' to this and I need to change this program so the program prints out the sum of the odd numbers in the list.

My question is how can I make a program that prints out the number of odd numbers in the list(codeA). Additionally, by changing least code from codeA to a program that prints out the sum of the odd numbers at the list(codeB).

Comment: what is your input exactly?

Comment: [1, 3, 31, 42, 52] something like this i will input random number in [ ]

Comment: if you convert this `[1, 3, 31, 42, 52]` to list it will become like this `['[', '1', ',', ' ', '3', ',', ' ', '3', '1', ',', ' ', '4', '2', ',', ' ', '5', '2', ']']`

Comment: Are you using python 2 or python 3? The `input` function is different.

Comment: i am using python 3!!

Comment: ohh than yeah i know how the list is work but dont know how to adapt this at the coding sorry i am bad at this. this site is my last hope

Comment: use this `numbers = list(map(int, input().split()))` and give input in space separated number like this `1 3 31 42 52`

Comment: thank you! i am trying my best by using your guys comments

Comment: Since input gives you a string anyway there's no need to enter the numbers as a list representation. Just use a comma (`,`) as a delimiter. If you do that your whole task could be wriiten as a one liner: `print(f"odd number : {sum(v%2 for v in map(int, input('list: ').split(',')))} 개")`

Comment: thanks for all that leave a comment for me i will be right back solving this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your input will come in as a string, you need to convert that to a list. This can be done with the [string.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function.

```
numbers = input('list: ')
# Convert, for example: "1, 3, 5" -> ["1", " 3", " 5"]
number = numbers.split(",")

total = 0

for a in number:
    # Since these numbers are strings, they need to be converted to
    # integers. You may also want to strip whitespace
    if int(a.strip()) % 2 == 1:
        total = total + 1

print("odd number : ", total)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code gives an error when I try this:

```
list: [1, 3, 31, 42, 52]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DELL/Documents/Python Progrms/temp.py", line 22, in <module>
    a = int(a)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '['
```

The problem is number list is not in a format you would expect. It is rather like this:

```
['[', '1', ',', ' ', '3', ',', ' ', '3', '1', ',', ' ', '4', '2', ',', ' ', '5', '2', ']']
```

So `int('[')` would result a `ValueError`.

To overcome this you could use a regex to capture numbers from your input, map() to convert them to int and then a filter() to filter the odd numbers.

Then you can use sum() and len() to get total and count of odd numbers.

```
import re

user_input = input('list: ')
number_list = map(int, re.findall(r'[-+]?\d+', user_input))
odd_number_list = list(filter(lambda number: True if number % 2 == 1 else False, number_list))

print("There are %d odd numbers and their sum is %d" % (len(odd_number_list), sum(odd_number_list)))
```

Now when I try the code, it worked for following types of inputs:

```
list: [1, 3, 31, 42, 52]
There are 3 odd numbers and their sum is 35

list: [1,3,31,42,-52]
There are 3 odd numbers and their sum is 35

list: 1,3,-31,42,52
There are 3 odd numbers and their sum is -27
```

Comment: Does this work for numbers greater than 9? This approach is flawed. Calling list() on a string returns a list of single chars. for list("1, 10") you will have ['1', ' ', '1', '0']

Comment: @DanielLee thanks for pointing out my mistake. It was a serious error. I've updated the algorithm now. Please check and point any errors in my code

Answer (score -2):

Here is a solution. When you read from keyboard with input, apparently in PyCharm takes every char and add it to list. So if you read 1,2,3,4 the list will look like ['1', ',', '2'...] so with try except you can skip any char that is not number.

Edited! Apparently in Python 3 the input is not evaluated as in Python 2 so you have to read the numbers one by one or else the input will be separated in chars.

```
no_of_vals = int(input("Numer of values: "))
a = []
for i in range(no_of_vals):
    a.append(int(input("Enter number:")))
no_of_odds = 0
sum_of_odds = 0
for number in a:
    if int(number) % 2 == 1:
        no_of_odds += 1
        sum_of_odds += int(number)
print("List: {0}".format(a))
print("No of odd numbers in list: {0}".format(no_of_odds))
print("Sum of the odd numbers in list: {0}".format(sum_of_odds))
```

Comment: That's not quite what's happening. You are calling list() on a string. This will not work for any numbers > 9